# NOT NULL constraint in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to use DynamoDB for creating tables. We don't have to specify all the column names while creating schema in DyamoDB and only the primary key(hash key + sort key[optional]). Now if my table does have some other attributes that I want to be there for every item inserted-i.e., add NOT NULL constraint to an attribute other than the key, then how can I achieve it in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `NotNull` constraint explicitly available on DynamoDB. However there is a feature to provide **default value** for the attribute if you are using [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html).

Also, DynamoDB API doesn't allow to add an attribute with empty value (i.e. Null or empty string ''). The API does throw an exception.

In other words, you don't need to define a constraint like RDBMS database. Also, there is no workaround to override this functionality. This condition applies to all attributes i.e you can't have any attributes with NULL or empty value.

**Example to set default value using annotation :-**

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedDefault("default")
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")  
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException:
>   Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the
>   supported datatypes (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:
>   1dd8288c-7151-43d3-83d0-dbb7842d705a)